# RegEx in windows file explorer

Tags: regex, windows, search

Is it possible to tell Windows 8 file explorer to search for file that name described using regular expression. For example I need to search for all html files except `index.html`. Something like `^[^index].+?.html$` in RegEx.

Comment: https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack

Answer (score 0):

No. This is also a feature that's rather unlikely to be added. This is usually the reason of shells and programming languages, which can handle this with ease, e.g. PowerShell:

```
gci -recurse *.html | ? Name -ne index.html
```